# Rewrite rule taxonomy url with different values in one function

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, urls, terms

So I'm a little bit stuck here and honestly don't know how to proceed, I'm trying to do a rewrite rule to a series of specific urls

I have a `movies` custom post type and an `alphabet` taxonomy and the terms A-Z, and I'm trying to make the url from `sample.com/alphabet/a` to `sample.com/movies/a`. So I tried this code in **functions.php** and it works for alphabet A.

```
function custom_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^movies/a/?', 'index.php?taxonomy=movies_alphabet&term=a', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rules');
```

**Question:** so my question is how to apply it on all alphabet? not just A but also the rest of the alphabets b,c,d,e,f,g,h,j without repeating writing `custom_rewrite_rules()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using [a subpattern or capturing group](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php) like `([a-z])` *in your rewrite rule's regex* (i.e. regular expression pattern, which is the 1st parameter for [`add_rewrite_rule()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/)), and then use `$matches[<n>]` *in your query* (the 2nd parameter for `add_rewrite_rule()`), where `<n>` is a number (`1` or above) and it's the subpattern's position number.

- Why use `$matches`: Because when matching the current URL against the rewrite rules on your site (i.e. rules which use `index.php`), WordPress will use [`preg_match()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match) with the 3rd parameter set to `$matches`.

So for example in your case, you can try this which should match `movies/a`, `movies/b`, `movies/c` and so on, and that the `$matches[1]` would be the alphabet after the slash (e.g. `c` as in `movies/c`):

```php
add_rewrite_rule(
    '^movies/([a-z])/?$',
    'index.php?taxonomy=movies_alphabet&term=$matches[1]',
    'top'
);
```

**Notes:**

- I added `$` to the regex, so that it only matches `movies/<alphabet>` like `movies/a` and *not* just anything that starts with that alphabet or path (e.g. `movies/aquaman` and `movies/ant-man`).
- See [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.meta.php) for more details on regex meta-characters like that `$`.
- You can play with the above regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/BUcbdi/1). <sub>( PS: You can learn regex via this site; just check the *explanation* for the specific regex pattern.. :) )</sub>

Don't forget to flush the rewrite rules — just visit the Permalink Settings admin page, without having to do anything else.

### Bonus

To support for **pagination**, e.g. the 2nd page at `https://example.com/movies/a/page/2/`, you can use the following regex and query:

*Note that we now have 2 capturing groups — `([a-z])` and `(\d+)` (the page number). `$matches[2]` is used to get the page number and will be the value of the query var named [`paged`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#pagination-parameters).*

```php
add_rewrite_rule(
    '^movies/([a-z])(?:/page/(\d+)|)/?$',
    'index.php?taxonomy=movies_alphabet&term=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]',
    'top'
);
```

You can test the regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/iKLNar/1), and once again, remember to flush the rewrite rules after making changes to your regex and/or query.

Happy coding!

Comment: awesome @sally-cj, it works, but there's an unforeseen bug, the posts of my `movies` custom post type cannot be visited... so I successfully rewrote the url with that, when I tried to visit `movies/aquaman` or `movies/ant-man`, it redirects me to `movies/a`

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice your regex didn't include a `$`.. So, try adding that - `^movies/([a-z])/?$` - then flush the rules again and see if the same issue persists? But, this is really for matching just a **single alphabet**, right?

Comment: Yes it works like charm!! thank you so much, i'm curious what does the `$` do? why it stops redirecting me to alphabetical pagination.  @sally-cj

Comment: See [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.meta.php) and you can play with the regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/BUcbdi/1). But basically, without that `$`, PHP will match anything that starts with `movies/<letter>` as in `movies/c` and `movies/casablanca`. Therefore we need to add `$` so that we target the correct URL *path* only.

Comment: Btw, I saw your other (new) post/question, so perhaps you should delete that post? :) (because you just needed the `$` to fix that issue)

Comment: I see, I see, thanks a ton! yeah I've already closed it, thanks again, dude like you is the reason I stay asking question like this in stackoverflow hahaha, have a blast!

Comment: Well, I'm a dudette...  and I just wanted to say, I've revised my answer. Hopefully it helps you more!